# Nordic Nrf51822. Where to get the clock source for external SPI Slave

Tags: spi, clock

I need to connect an external SPI device . Cannot figure out where do get the Clock source for Nrf51822. 
The datasheet says:
"The GPIOs used for each SPI interface line can be chosen from any GPIO on the device and are
independently configurable. This enables great flexibility in device pinout and efficient use of printed circuit
board space and signal routing.
The SPI peripheral supports SPI mode 0, 1, 2, and 3." 
But no mention about the clock. Can I reuse somehow the clock reference (crystal) used by the Nrf51822 chip or I need to create an ad-hoc clock reference for slave SPI ?

Comment: The SPI clock is sourced by the SPI master.  An SPI master function in an MCU tends to produce a clock by dividing down the processor's clock (or a peripheral clock already divided therefrom).  The reference you paraphrase seems to indicate that you can choose the SPI clock pin fairly widely, rather than being restricted to only a few possibilities.

Comment: So I can use a GPIO pin for clock ?